# How to use Laravel Translation String? It does not work

Tags: laravel

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have it in resources/lang/de/de.json but somehow it just doesn't work...

I tested it with

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    app()->setLocale('de');
    echo __('good');
    dd(app()->getLocale());
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And I get:

```
good
"de"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not quite how translations work; you can't just provide a string and expect a valid translation for it. You need to define and reference them properly.

In `resources/lang`, by default you should have a folder `en`, which can contain any number of files. In your case, add one for `general.php`, with the following:

```
<?php return [
  "good" => "good"
];
```

Now, add a corresponding `de` folder and file (`resources/lang/de/general.php`):

```
<?php return [
  "good" => "gut"
];
```

Now, when calling `__("general.good")` (or `trans("general.good")`, depending on Laravel version), based on your current `locale` you should get `"good"` or `"gut"`:

```
// Default locale is `en` unless overridden
echo __("general.good"); // "good"
app()->setLocale("de");
echo __("general.good"); // "gut"
```

Note: Anytime a translation fails, it will literally echo whatever you tried to translate, so `app()->setLocale("es); echo __("general.good");` will echo `"general.good"` as the translation folder/file for `es.general.good` is not defined.

Edit:

After realizing that we are attempting to use Translation Strings, I noted that the current path of `de.json` was a bit off when compared to that provided in the example:

```
/resources/lang/de/de.json
/resources/lang/es.json
```

It seems that when using Translation Strings, the `.json` file is to be saved in the `/resources/lang` directory, and no in the language-specific sub-directory.

Comment: I'm sorry I was away and could not answer straight away. But what you described is just normal localization. I want to use translations string look at Using Translation Strings As Keys https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#defining-translation-strings

Comment: they even have an example: "I love programming.": "Me encanta programar."

Comment: Hmm... I see that now; sorry. Never used em like that, but at a glance, it might have to do with where your `json` file is saved. You're using `/resources/lang/de/de.json`, but the example references `/resources/lang/es.json`, which is 1 directory up from yours. Try `/resources/lang/de.json`

Comment: OH stupid me!!! Yes that was it ! Thank you. Please change your answer so that I can except it

Comment: Same mistake here. It happened because I copied all the default translations (es) to the `/lang/es` directory and `es.json` was there too.. Moving up one folder and fixed it. Thanks!!